# What method can solve the following equation: $6xy -y +x = 16$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

What method can solve the following equation?

$$\forall \, y, x \, \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$6xy -y +x = 16$$

Comment: $\forall \, y, x \, \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Your tag of "linear-algebra" makes people think you meant $\mathbb{R}$. I've modified your tag. If you disagree please adjust it.

Comment: Wolframalpha returns the following possible results:
$\{x=-3, y=-1\}, \{x = 0, y = -16\}, \{x = 1, y = 3\}, \{x = 16, y = 0\}$
How does the system get to these results?

Comment: For $y=0$, $x=16$. For $y\not=0$, $|(16-x)/(6x-1)|\ge 1\implies -3\le x\le 2$.

Comment: you can use this online solver and do a step by step calculation to see how it's done. https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$6xy-y+x=16$$
$$6\cdot6xy-6y+6x=6\cdot16$$
$$6\cdot6xy-6y+6x-1=6\cdot16-1$$
$$6y(6x-1)+(6x-1)=6\cdot16-1$$
$$(6x-1)(6y+1)=6\cdot16-1$$
$$(6x-1)(6y+1)=95$$

Comment: And which values $ \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy Eq.?

Comment: OK, But how can I determine the values of x and y?

Comment: @DarioGutierrez Consider $x'=6x-1$ and $y'=6y+1$ both in $\mathbb Z$ and solve for those.

Comment: $95=1\cdot 95=5\cdot17$

Comment: @Roman83 and also $(-1) \cdot (-95)=(-5)(-19)=95$ ;-)

Comment: ??  $5 \cdot 17 = 85$

Comment: @ctst: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @DarioGutierrez 95=5\cdot19